# iOS app crashes on push segue, but only on installation

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

On first installation of my app, I try to perform a push to segue. I embedded the UINavigationController.

But when I try to push the button to go to my second viewController, the app crashes and I get this error:

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'"

But it only happens on the first try, on installation. If I change nothing and run the app again, the segue successfully sends me to the second view controller.

Any ideas as to what is going on? Let me know what more information I need to provide.

EDIT

I do have UIPageViewControllers as app intro screens at the beginning.

In the AppDelegate.m I have

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"]) {
UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *walkthrough =
[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IntroViewController"];
[self.window setRootViewController:walkthrough];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"hasSeenTutorial"];
}
return YES;
```

And I have a button on the UIPageView that sends the user to the ViewController that starts the beginning

```
- (IBAction)ready:(id)sender {


UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController =
[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Comment: How do you know its the same segue and the exact same set of circumstances on first installation and other runs?

Comment: I put in an edit that explains the situation at the beginning

Comment: The error message describes exactly the problem: "Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController." You have a push segue but you are not pushing the view controller onto a navigation stack. If you don't have a navigation controller in the app and don't intend to have one then don't make the type of the segues 'push'. If you app is intended to have a navigation controller but doesn't then add one and push the view controllers onto it. Whether your app should or should not have a nav controller is a different question.

Comment: I did have a navigation controller. I just didn't send the user to the navigation controller after the user finishes the intro screens that appear first installation. I sent them to the ViewController. Now that I sent them to the navigation controller after they look at the intro screens, app is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case anyone ever runs into this problem, after the intro screens, I sent the user to the NavigationViewController instead of the ViewController like so

```
- (IBAction)ready:(id)sender {


UIStoryboard *storyBoard;
storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController =
[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationViewController"];
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

And that got the segues to working. Thanks to Martin H for prompting the exploration.